# Trouble using Find and Prune Command to filter out file name in GitLab runner

Tags: linux, find, gitlab, runner, basename

So, this is strange and I'm not sure what is causing it.. (I'm very new to cli stuff)

I have a directory ==> `SomeDirectory`
I have two jar files ==> `original-processor.jar      and   processor.jar`
I am looking to just return `processor.jar` and set it as a variable, basically anytime there is an original-* I want to ignore it.

I do the following within EC2 (amazon linux) and it works

```
JAR_FILE_NAME=$(basename $( find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*original*.jar' -prune -o -name '*.jar' -print))
```

Output ==> `processor.jar`

But when i run this exact same command in GitLab's cicd pipeline:

Output ==> `original-processor.jar`

Does anyone know what the discrepancy could be? Is this the best way to accomplish what I want?

I appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-prune` is only meaningful for directories, it prevents descending into it. It has no effect when the element is a file.

If you want to exclude something from the results, use `-not` before the criteria.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.jar' -not -name '*original*.jar'
```

If you're using `bash`, you can enable extended globbing and use the negative matching operator.

```
shopt -s extglob
JAR_FILE_NAME=$(echo !(*original*).jar)
```

Comment: Thanks, Barmar. That got it.